# ReactNative: place a view on top of the border of a Circle-View

Tags: react-native

I have built a component, that draws a colored circle of a given size. In the center of the circle a number or character is shown:

[image]

Also, a green circle should be displayed on the bottom-right-corner at the border of the circle.

The ReactNative-StyleSheet looks as follows:

```
  circle: {
    width: 100, // this should be a "props"-value in future
    height: 100, // this should be a "props"-value in future
    borderRadius: 100/2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  circleCaption: {
    fontSize: 70,
  },

  symbol: {
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    borderRadius: 16/2,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 8,
    bottom: 8,
  },
```

And the shape is placed into the view this way:

```
    <View style={s.circle}>
      <Text style={s.circleCaption}>A</Text>
      <View style={s.symbol} />
    </View>
```

With these factors (right: 8, bottom: 8), the green circle is placed directly on the right/bottom-corner of the circle.

How to place it dynamically with circle-sizes? How can I calculate the bottom/right-value?

Also, if the character, number or symbol that is drawn in the center of the red circle would become too large to fit in the circle, the green circle is way off the circle and loses its fixed position. Any ideas about? Unfortunately, there is no Z-Index provided by ReactNative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to do it is to use a formula for calculating position of a point on a circle:

```
x = r * cos(a) + cx
y = r * sin(a) + cy
```

where

`x` and `y` - point position we want to find

`r` - radius of the circle

`a` - angle (we need 45 degrees)

`cx` and `cy` - circle center point position

Note that in JS `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` take angle in radians as an argument, so we should convert `45` angle from degrees to radians.

```
function degToRad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

All dynamic styles have been moved inside the component, here is what left:

```
const s = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  circleCaption: {
    fontSize: 70,
  },
  symbol: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

And the component itself:

```
export default function Circle(props) {
  const { size, symbolSize } = props;

  const angleRad = degToRad(45);
  const radius = size / 2;
  const center = radius;

  // Calculate symbol position
  // Subtract half of symbol size to center it on the circle
  const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
  const y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;

  return (
    <View
      style={[s.circle, {
        width: size,
        height: size,
        borderRadius: size / 2,
      }]}
    >
      <Text style={s.circleCaption}>A</Text>
      <View
        style={[
          s.symbol, {
            width: symbolSize,
            height: symbolSize,
            borderRadius: symbolSize / 2,
            left: x,
            top: y,
        }]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Usage example:

```
<Circle
  size={100}
  symbolSize={16}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, it helped me a lot!